# Scheduling and scaling pods in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

i am running k8s cluster on GKE

it has 4 node pool with different configuration

**Node pool : 1** (Single node coroned status)

Running **Redis & RabbitMQ**

**Node pool : 2** (Single node coroned status)

Running **Monitoring & Prometheus**

**Node pool : 3** (Big large single node)

Application pods

**Node pool : 4** (Single node with auto-scaling enabled)

Application pods

currently, i am running single replicas for each service on GKE

however 3 replicas of the main service which mostly manages everything.

when scaling this main service with HPA sometime seen the issue of Node getting crashed or `kubelet frequent restart` PODs goes to Unkown state.

How to handle this scenario ? If the node gets crashed GKE taking time to auto repair and which cause service down time.

**Question : 2**

Node pool : 3 -4 running application PODs. Inside the application, there are 3-4 memory-intensive micro services i am also thinking same to use **Node selector** and fix it on one Node.

while only small node pool will run main service which has HPA and node auto scaling auto work for that node pool.

however i feel like it's not best way to it with Node selector.

it's always best to run more than one replicas of each service but currently, we are running single replicas only of each service so please suggest considering that part.

Comment: if you have a single node, you leave yourself with a single point of failure. Also keep in mind that autoscaling takes time to kick in and is based on resource requests. If your node suffers OOM because of memory intensive workloads, you need to readjust your memory requests and limits

Comment: thankyou so much for your reply and suggestion. i will look into to for sure to readjust the  requests and limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Patrick W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9231144/patrick-w) rightly suggested in his comment:

> **if you have a single node, you leave yourself with a single point of
> failure**. Also keep in mind that **autoscaling takes time to kick in and
> is based on resource requests**. **If your node suffers OOM because of
> memory intensive workloads, you need to readjust your memory requests
> and limits** – Patrick W Oct 10 at

you may need to redesign a bit your infrastructure so you have more than a single node in every nodepool as well as [readjust mamory requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/)

You may want to take a look at the following sections in the **official kubernetes docs** and **Google Cloud blog**:

- [Managing Resources for Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)
- [Assign CPU Resources to Containers and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/)
- [Configure Default Memory Requests and Limits for a Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/)
- [Resource Quotas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/)
- [Kubernetes best practices: Resource requests and limits](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits)

> How to handle this scenario ? If the node gets crashed GKE taking time
> to auto repair and which cause service down time.

That's why having more than just one node for a single node pool can be much better option. It greatly reduces the likelihood that you'll end up in the situation described above. **GKE** **autorapair** feature needs to take its time (usually a few minutes) and if this is your only node, you cannot do much about it and need to accept possible downtimes.

> Node pool : 3 -4 running application PODs. Inside the application,
> there are 3-4 memory-intensive micro services i am also thinking same
> to use Node selector and fix it on one Node.
>
> while only small node pool will run main service which has HPA and
> node auto scaling auto work for that node pool.
>
> however i feel like it's not best way to it with Node selector.

You may also take a loot at [node affinity and anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) as well as [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)

Comment: i have question if i have stateful set running in single pod what if that node goes down ?

Comment: If you have additional node, `Statefulset` will try to deploy such `Pod` on the second node. `Statefulset` manages your `Pods` the same way as `Deployment`. If you even delete such `Pod` by yourself, this higher abstraction objects will ensure that the `Pod` is up and running, of course if there is a node, on which it can be scheduled.

Comment: Great got it thank a lot for answer now i am much clear on part.