# GKE autoscaler not scaling down the nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a google Kubernetes engine with autoscale enabled with minimum and maximum nodes. A few days ago I deployed couple of servers on production which increased the nodes count as expected. but when I deleted those deployments I expect it to resize the nodes which are to scale down. I waited more than an hour but it still did not scale down.

- All my other pods are controlled by replica controller since I deployed with kind: deployment.
- All my statefulset pods are using PVC as volume.

I'm not sure what prevented the nodes to scale down so I manually scaled the nodes for now. Since I made the changes manually I can not get the autoscaler logs now.

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

GKE version is 1.16.15-gke.4300

As mentioned in this link
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node

- I'm not using any local storage.
- pods not having PodDisruptionBudget(don't know what is that)
- Pods are created by deployments (helm charts)
- **only thing is I don't have "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "true" this annotation. is this must?**

Comment: Is it possible to provide more details, like your YAML configurations like deployments, pvc, did you use in your configuration anything what is mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node) ? What GKE version are you using? or maybe you hit some [GKE autoscaler limitations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#limitations)

Answer (score 6):

I have tested `Cluster Autoscaler` on my GKE cluster. It work's bit differently than you expected.

#### Backgorund

You can enable autoscaling using command or enable it during creation like it's described [in this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler).

In [Cluster Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler) documentation you can find various information like `Operation criteria`, `Limitations`, etc.

As I mentioned in comment section, [Cluster Autoscaler - Frequently Asked Questions](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node) won't work if will encounter one of below situation:

> Pods with restrictive PodDisruptionBudget.
>
> Kube-system pods that:
>
> - are not run on the node by default, *
> - don't have a pod disruption budget set or their PDB is too restrictive (since CA 0.6).
>
> Pods that are not backed by a controller object (so not created by deployment, replica set, job, statefulset etc). *
>
> Pods with local storage. *
>
> Pods that cannot be moved elsewhere due to various constraints (lack of resources, non-matching node selectors or affinity, matching anti-affinity, etc)
>
> Pods that have the following annotation set:
> `"cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false"`

For my tests I've used 6 nodes, with `autoscaling range 1-6` and `nginx` application with requests `cpu: 200m` and `memory: 128Mi`.

As OP mentioned that is not able to provide autoscaler logs, I will paste my logs from `Logs Explorer`. Description of how they can be achieved is in [Viewing cluster autoscaler events](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#viewing_events) documentation.

In those logs you should search `noScaleDown` events. You will find there a few information, however the most important is:

```
reason: {
parameters: [
0: "kube-dns-66d6b7c877-hddgs"
]
messageId: "no.scale.down.node.pod.kube.system.unmovable"
```

As it's described in [NoScaleDown node-level reasons](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#noscaledown-node-level-reasons) for `"no.scale.down.node.pod.kube.system.unmovable"`:

> Pod is blocking scale down because it's a non-daemonset, non-mirrored, non-pdb-assigned kube-system pod. See the Kubernetes [Cluster Autoscaler FAQ](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md) for more details.

#### Solution

If you want to make `Cluster Autoscaler` work on `GKE`, you have to create [Disruptions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#how-disruption-budgets-work) with proper information, how to create it can be found in [How to set PDBs to enable CA to move kube-system pods?](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-to-set-pdbs-to-enable-ca-to-move-kube-system-pods)

```
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget <pdb name> --namespace=kube-system --selector app=<app name> --max-unavailable 1
```

where you have to specify the correct `selector` and `--max-unavailable` or `--min-available` depends on your needs. For more details, please read [Specifying a PodDisruptionBudget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#specifying-a-poddisruptionbudget) documentation.

#### Tests

```
$ kubectl get deploy,nodes
NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment   16/16   16           16          66m

NAME                                            STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-1ckn   Ready    <none>   11m     v1.16.15-gke.6000
node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-2j4j   Ready    <none>   11m     v1.16.15-gke.6000
node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-388n   Ready    <none>   3h33m   v1.16.15-gke.6000
node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-5x35   Ready    <none>   3h33m   v1.16.15-gke.6000
node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-pdfk   Ready    <none>   3h33m   v1.16.15-gke.6000
node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-wqtm   Ready    <none>   11m     v1.16.15-gke.6000
$ kubectl get pdb -A
NAMESPACE     NAME      MIN AVAILABLE   MAX UNAVAILABLE   ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS   AGE
kube-system   kubedns   1               N/A               1                     43m
```

**Scaledown deployment**

```
$ kubectl scale deploy nginx-deployment --replicas=2
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment scaled
```

After a while (~10-15 minutes) in the event viewer you will find the `Decision` event and inside you will find information that the node was deleted.

```
...
scaleDown: {
nodesToBeRemoved: [
0: {
node: {
mig: {
zone: "europe-west2-c"
nodepool: "default-pool"
name: "gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-grp"
}
name: "gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-wqtm"
```

Number of nodes decreased:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-2j4j   Ready    <none>   30m     v1.16.15-gke.6000
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-388n   Ready    <none>   3h51m   v1.16.15-gke.6000
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-5x35   Ready    <none>   3h51m   v1.16.15-gke.6000
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-pdfk   Ready    <none>   3h51m   v1.16.15-gke.6000
```

Another place where you can confirm it's scaling down is `kubectl get events  --sort-by='.metadata.creationTimestamp'`

**Output:**

```
5m16s       Normal    NodeNotReady                                                                                             node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-wqtm   Node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-wqtm status is now: NodeNotReady
4m56s       Normal    NodeNotReady                                                                                             node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-1ckn   Node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-1ckn status is now: NodeNotReady
4m          Normal    Deleting node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-wqtm because it does not exist in the cloud provider   node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-wqtm   Node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-wqtm event: DeletingNode
3m55s       Normal    RemovingNode                                                                                             node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-wqtm   Node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-wqtm event: Removing Node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-wqtm from Controller
3m50s       Normal    Deleting node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-1ckn because it does not exist in the cloud provider   node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-1ckn   Node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-1ckn event: DeletingNode
3m45s       Normal    RemovingNode                                                                                             node/gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-1ckn   Node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-1ckn event: Removing Node gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6d42fa0a-1ckn from Controller
```

#### Conclusion

By default, `kube-system` pods prevent CA from removing nodes on which they are running. Users can manually add `PDBs`  for the `kube-system` pods that can be safely rescheduled elsewhere. It can be achieved using:

```
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget <pdb name> --namespace=kube-system --selector app=<app name> --max-unavailable 1
```

List of possible reasons why `CA` won't autoscale can be found in [Cluster Autoscaler - Frequently Asked Questions](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node).

To verify which pods could still block `CA` downscale, you can use [Autoscaler Events](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#viewing_events).

Comment: what if we want to scale the node when the average utilization of other reaches 70% is it possible?

Comment: what i have seen i am running single replicas of most of micro services due to some limitation but only 2-3 service are scalable  with HPA. all service have resource limit and request set but when HPA scales those services either node crash due to memory pressure or pod evicted.

Comment: @HarshManvar I think it would be better if you create new question with more details, your environment, your current config and your expectations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668397/gke-cluster-autoscaler-profile-for-older-luster

Comment: this is similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287099/scheduling-and-scaling-pods-in-kubernetes

Comment: Do you know what I'm supposed to put for "app=<app name>"?

Comment: In this example app was one of the labels. You can find additional information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#syntax-and-character-set) In docs example you have `app: nginx`. It depends on how you named your resources.

Comment: If I just created a cluster and set up the autoscaling but have not deployed any application yet, what should I put `<app>` to eliminate the warning `Pod is blocking scale down because it's a non-daemonset, non-mirrored, non-pdb-assigned kube-system pod. See the Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler FAQ for more details.`

Comment: In my case scale down to 2 nodes works fine even without setting up PBD.
But scaling down to 1 node doesn't work with PBD

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with Kubernetes Autoscaler. In my case it was **Kube-dns** pod which was blocking Autoscaler to shutdown the node. I tried creating **PodDistributionBudget** for Kube-dns pod but didn't fix the error.

**Solution**: Just add the annotation **"cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "true"** to affected pod (in my case 'kube-dns' pod) by updating affected pod Yaml file.

To add this annotation **by default** to affected pod just update the template for that perticular pod and it will add this annotation to all existing affected pod and also create new affected pod with the annotation.