# How to Solve Pod is blocking scale down because it's a non-daemonset in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm getting below this issue in GKS
Pod is blocking scale down because it's a non-daemonset, non-mirrored, non-pdb-assigned kube-system pod

I have read this docs :-
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-to-set-pdbs-to-enable-ca-to-move-kube-system-pods

but still not able to understand where i need to add this line in every pods or every nodes. if pods which i need to add.

In default namespace im running my application in which pods,svc,deploy are running. So i need to add under defaults namespace of pods or kube-system namespace pods

"cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/scale-down-disabled": "true"
even i have add in 3 nodes like this

kubectl annotate node gke-test-default-pool-a44dbf1c-05h1 cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/scale-down-disabled=true
kubectl annotate node gke-test-default-pool-a44dbf1c-3j6j cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/scale-down-disabled=true
kubectl annotate node gke-test-default-pool-a44dbf1c-hmrf cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/scale-down-disabled=true

but still the error is showing on GKE

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please tell me how to solve that error/issue in GKS from 3 days im not able to understand and solve it even i google it and ready so many website but didnt solve it.

After deploying

```
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget pdb --namespace=kube-system --selector k8s-app=kube-dns --max-unavailable 1
Warning: policy/v1beta1 PodDisruptionBudget is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use policy/v1 PodDisruptionBudget
poddisruptionbudget.policy/pdb created
```

I Got deprecated and another issue
[image]

Previous i was having 3 nodes but i have 2 nodes only now because i have edit one node remove this line **"cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/scale-down-disabled": "true"** which i have added in it after that i didnt check whether my nodes are 3 or 2.

Later i check found only 2 nodes are running.

Its a good or bad to edit nodes in GKE or AKS

```
kubectl get pdb -A
NAMESPACE     NAME           MIN AVAILABLE   MAX UNAVAILABLE   ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS   AGE
kube-system   kube-dns-bbc   N/A             1                 1                     69m
```

Here is yaml file

```
kubectl get pdb kube-dns-bbc -o yaml -n kube-system 

apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"policy/v1","kind":"PodDisruptionBudget","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"k8s-app":"kube-dns"},"name":"kube-dns-bbc","namespace":"kube-system"},"spec":{"maxUnavailable":1,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"k8s-app":"kube-dns"}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-18T17:07:53Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
  name: kube-dns-bbc
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "230860"
  uid: 7131c64d-6779-4b23-8c53-10ffcc242144
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kube-dns
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-02-18T17:38:13Z"
    message: ""
    observedGeneration: 1
    reason: SufficientPods
    status: "True"
    type: DisruptionAllowed
  currentHealthy: 2
  desiredHealthy: 1
  disruptionsAllowed: 1
  expectedPods: 2
  observedGeneration: 1
```

Comment: Did you already check your Kubernetes server version? To specify a Pod Disruption Budget for your application, your Kubernetes server must be at or later than version v1.21. To check the version, enter “kubectl version”.

Comment: @IsmaelClementeAguirre yes check got this client v1.21.9-dispatcher and server v1.21.6-gke.1500

Comment: I can see that you created your PDB, and it seems to be working. Did that solve your issue? If not, is it the same issue that you stated in your original post? Or do you have another question?

Comment: it didnt solve same issue only i have just update it with few points added

Comment: Was the information posted in the answer helpful for you? Or, do you consider that you need more information in order to resolve your issue or doubt?

Answer (score 0):

> I have read this docs :-
> https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-to-set-pdbs-to-enable-ca-to-move-kube-system-pods
>
> but still not able to understand where i need to add this line in
> every pods or every nodes. if pods which i need to add.

You don't add to pod or node, you need to create PDB for pod in kube-system so that CA knows it is safe to evict such pods from the node that is suppose to be remove. Example for coreDNS:

`kubectl create poddisruptionbudget <name> --namespace=kube-system --selector k8s-app=kube-dns --max-unavailable 1`

Comment: i have create POD kubectl create poddisruptionbudget pdb --namespace=kube-system --selector k8s-app=kube-dns --max-unavailable 1
and got below warning
Warning: policy/v1beta1 PodDisruptionBudget is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use policy/v1 PodDisruptionBudget
poddisruptionbudget.policy/pdb created
after typing this command "kubectl get all -n kube-system" i didnt find my PDB POD is created. I want to see where it install 
now tell me how do i know it work or resolve my issue any time or command to see

Comment: i have update my question in above please read again let me know what to do

Comment: Base on your update it is working now. You can try trigger scale-up and confirm that.

Comment: it only scale-down not trigger scale-up

Answer (score 0):

In the link that you share it is stated:

By default, kube-system pods prevent CA from removing nodes on which they are running. Users can manually add PDBs for the kube-system pods that can be safely rescheduled elsewhere:

```
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget <pdb name> --namespace=kube-system --selector app=<app name> --max-unavailable 1
```

> A PDB limits the number of Pods of a replicated application that are
> down simultaneously from voluntary disruptions. For example, a
> quorum-based application would like to ensure that the number of
> replicas running is never brought below the number needed for a quorum

You can find more information about disruptions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/).

Specifying a Disruption Budget for your Application [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#specifying-a-poddisruptionbudget)
.

Also a complete tutorial about [Pod Disruption Budget for helping manually upgrading GKE Cluster](https://faun.pub/day-2-kubernetes-pod-disruption-budget-for-helping-manually-upgrading-gke-cluster-basic-stuff-a1de430ed10).

**[What types of pods can prevent CA from removing a node?](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node)**

> Pods with restrictive PodDisruptionBudget.
>
> Kube-system pods that:
>
> - are not run on the node by default, *
> - don't have a pod disruption budget set or their PDB is too    restrictive (since CA 0.6).
> - Pods that are not backed by a controller object (so not created by    deployment, replica set, job, stateful set etc). *
> - Pods with local storage. *
> - Pods that cannot be moved elsewhere due to various constraints (lack    of resources, non-matching node selectors or affinity,
>   matching    anti-affinity, etc)
>
> Pods that have the following annotation set:
>
> - "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false"
> - *Unless the pod has the following annotation (supported in CA 1.0.3 or later):
> - "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "true"
>
> Or you have overridden this behavior with one of the relevant flags.
> See below for [more information on these flags](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-are-the-parameters-to-ca).

You can use [Autoscaler events](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#viewing_events) to review your pods, and see which one is causing the blocking of the CA to downscale.

Adding to this, you can find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65811347/16922342) in another question to solve more doubts that you can have.